# Can I link a CSS file to HTML-Code external (without changing HTML code)?

Tags: html, css

I have a Project where I can't change any HTML code. So I have a css file that changes some stuff around and need that to be linked. Changing the HTML external would work.

So I have a HTML and a CSS file witch need to be linked without touching the HTML.

Comment: Your question is somewhat clear but does not provide with your current progress/examples. Please take look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do you 'link' to the external HTML?

Comment: well there is no link so i would like to make one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. The CSS file needs to be linked within the HTML file via `<link>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Applying styles to each element via JavaScript on page load may be a way. But still not the perfect one.

Comment: @Dario Probably you have some script file already included. It would be good to have more details about your HTML file, is it a part of any framework, cms, and so on.

Comment: nope there is no script... and its not on a framework. I found this: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> maybe we can do something with that?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you just need to add the following code inside your  tag in your html page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourcss.css">
```

provide the path name of your css file for the 'href' field.

Comment: yeah I know how to do that. But I need a external option without even touching the HTML.